# Starting from scratch.

Tags: beginner, newbie, pro-tools, starter

Hey guys. I have been using Nuendo ever since i entered this field and now with time, i am moving to protools. This might sound a bit immature, but i have no idea about how to start up? Which imac/ mac book pro should i buy? which protools version is the best? What all hardware do you require to make it run smoothly? How can i get myself going on protools. I know these are all basic things i should be knowing, but its the first time i'l be working on a mac. 
Thanks.

Comment: May I ask why you are moving from Nuendo to ProTools?

Comment: because i have never worked on a mac before and i also need to know protools as its like an industry standard. Thats why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First decide whether you want a desktop or a laptop.

After that just purchase the model you can afford, all of the current iMacs and MacBook Pros will run Pro Tools 10.

I run Pro Tools 10 on a 2.3 GHz i5 MacBook Pro and the software runs really smoothly.  I also use PT on a 4 year old iMac as well as a 6 year old Mac Pro, I even have PT running on a 5 year old MacBook.

After that you will need an iLok, and that's all you need to get started.